# Physical importance of centrifugal force and Coriolis force in the context of the restricted 3-body problem

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, centrifugal-force, coriolis-effect, accretion-disk

In the textbook [Galactic Dynamics (Binney and Tremaine)](http://www.tevza.org/home/course/AF2016/books/Galactic%20Dynamics,%20James%20Binney%20(2ed.,%20).pdf), the *restricted three-body problem* to find the trajectory of a test mass that orbits in the combined gravitational field of two masses $M$ and $m$ is discussed in Sec. 8.3.1. The two masses orbit their common center-of-mass with angular velocity $$\Omega=\sqrt{\frac{G(M+m)}{R_0^3}}$$
where $R_0$ is the separation between the masses and $G$ is the gravitational constant.

Now, a coordinate system is chosen to be centered at the center-of-mass and that rotates at angular velocity $\Omega$, so that the gravitational field is stationary in that coordinate system. The two-dimensional rotating potential (discussed in Sec. 3.3.2) is used to study the orbits of the test particle.

The conserved Jacobi integral in the rotating frame can be written as
$$E_J=\frac{1}{2}|\dot{\mathbf{x}}|^2+\Phi-\frac{1}{2}|\mathbf{\Omega}\times\mathbf{x}|^2=\frac{1}{2}|\dot{\mathbf{x}}|^2+\Phi_\mathscr{eff}$$

where the effective potential $\Phi_\mathscr{eff}$ is given by

$$\Phi_\mathscr{eff}(\mathbf{x})=\Phi(\mathbf{x})-\frac{1}{2}|\mathbf{\Omega}\times\mathbf{x}|^2=\Phi(\mathbf{x})-\frac{1}{2}\left[|\mathbf{\Omega}|^2|\mathbf{x}|^2-(\mathbf{\Omega}\cdot\mathbf{x})^2\right]$$

*Here, we can easily observe that the effective potential is the sum of the gravitational and a repulsive **centrifugal potential**.*

Then, we can obtain the following Hamilton's equations:
$$\mathbf{\dot{p}}=-\nabla\Phi-(\mathbf{\Omega}\times\mathbf{p})$$
$$\mathbf{\dot{x}}=\mathbf{p}-(\mathbf{\Omega}\times\mathbf{x})$$

Eliminating $\mathbf{p}$ between these equations we find
$$\mathbf{\ddot{x}}=-\nabla\Phi-\left[2\mathbf{\Omega}\times\mathbf{\dot{x}}\right]-\left[\mathbf{\Omega\times(\Omega\times x)}\right]$$

From this equation, we define

> **Coriolis force:** $\mathbf{F}_\mathscr{cor}=-2\mathbf{\Omega}\times\mathbf{\dot{x}}$
>
> **Centrifugal force:** $\mathbf{F}_\mathscr{cf}=-\mathbf{\Omega\times(\Omega\times x)}$

The following are my questions associated with the problem:

> **Question 1:** The effective potential (as written above) is a sum of the gravitational potential and a repulsive centrifugal potential. There is no term that corresponds to the Coriolis force. However, the Coriolis force appears in the equations of motion that depends on $\mathbf{\dot{x}}$. *So I think that the Coriolis term arises naturally due to the behavior of the Hamilton's equation rather than the exact form of $\Phi_{\mathscr{eff}}$*. **Is this correct or am I wrong?**
>
> **Question 2:** Since both centrifugal and Coriolis forces appear in the equations of motion obtained from the effective potential $\Phi_\mathscr{eff}$, both these forces should affect the test particle motion in the restricted three-body problem. **I am interested to know how these two forces affect the test particle motion at different Lagrangian points (in particular, $L_1$, that lies midway between the two masses and is important in modelling accretion disks)**. In most textbooks, only the effect of the centrifugal force is considered.

**NOTE:** My question is different from the following other questions on Physics.SE: [How are the Lagrange points determined?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363178/133767) , [Why are $L_4$ and $L_5$ lagrangian points stable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36092/133767) , [Why are the Lagrangian points $L_1$, $L_2$ & $L_3$ unstable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/286642/133767)