# 5 Lagrangian points: why isn't there a line of stability between $L_1$ and $L_4$ and $L_1$ and $L_5$ respectively?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, equilibrium, celestial-mechanics, stability

Given the 5 Lagrangian points of two large orbiting bodies:

[image]

(from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point)),

why isn't there a line of stability between L1 and L4 and L1 and L5 respectively (as depicted in red in the modified picture)?:

[image]

Comment: why should there be?

Comment: Why isn’t there? Because the math says so.

Comment: There are 10 line segments between 5 points. If there were lines of stability (and there are not), why would they be those two?

Comment: I think the point is pretty clear now - before asking why something doesn't happen, one should have a reasonable argument as to why they would expect it happen.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363178/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Of the links on that page https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36092/123208 is quite helpful.