# Roche lobes in binary star systems

Tags: newtonian-gravity, astrophysics, centrifugal-force, binary-stars, three-body-problem

While studying mass transfer in binary star systems, I came across the concept of [Roche lobes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_lobe) and the role of the inner Lagrangian point $L_1$, as shown in the adjoining figure.
[image: Roche lobe]

However, I am having a doubt in understanding the reason of the fact that one lobe is larger and the other is smaller. I think that the reason is due to the different masses of the two stars. Since the contours are equipotentials, it seems that larger the mass of a star, the larger is the size of the corresponding lobe. But I am not sure whether this is the exact reason.

So, I am looking for a proper reason for the different sizes of the two lobes.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363178/2451

Answer (score 1):

You are right: the size of the Roche lobe depends on the mass of the components. It scales linearly with the separation of the components and in addition is a function of the mass ratio. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_lobe