# How does Lagrange point $L_2$ provide even meta-stability if centrifugal force isn't real?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, orbital-motion, centrifugal-force

I recall hearing, perhaps colloquially, that a centri*fugal* force doesn't exist. It can be mistakenly *felt* but, it is not a real force. Given this, how does the $L_2$ orbital point exist beyond the earth? The two major gravities are in, towards the system. What force is pulling outward, to counteract the Sun+Earth's gravity, and thus providing [meta-stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metastability) to the $L_2$ point? Am I thinking about the forces incorrectly?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/123/

Comment: Our canonical question about centrifugal force is https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109500/123208 Do you have a specific question that isn't covered by the answers there?

Comment: Related: [How are the Lagrange points determined?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363178/2451)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing about the Lagrange "point" is that it is not an *actual* point, i.e., there is not a single location in space where the orbiting satellite is fixed. Instead, the satellite is on a moving, circular orbit, which has the special characteristic of being at a fixed location relative to the Earth (which is also moving!).

In other words, the satellite is at a fixed point in space *in the non-inertial frame where the Earth is also stationary*. And since that frame is not inertial, you need to include "fictional" forces that do not actually "exist" in the inertial frame of the solar system.