# When calculating Lagrange points, $L_3$, $L_4$ and $L_5$ are good, but why are my $L_1$ and $L_2$ too close to the Earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, equilibrium, centrifugal-force

I'm using python to calculate the Lagrange points of the Sun-Earth system. I started assuming that - for $L_1$ at least - the sum of the gravitational acceleration towards the Sun and the centripetal acceleration towards the Sun should balance with the gravitational acceleration from the Earth:
$$
\frac{GM_\odot}{r^2} + \omega^2 r - \frac{GM_\oplus}{(R-r)^2} = 0 
$$
where $R$ is the Sun-Earth distance (149.6 million km), and $r$ is the distance from the Earth to $L_1$.
Rearranging, I got a quintic equation in $r$, calculated the coefficients and asked `numpy.poly1d` to find the roots. I got five complex roots, which, when plotted, look like this:

[image: The five Lagrange points in the Sun-Earth system. L1 and L2 cannot be discerned at this scale.]

Bingo! I was overjoyed when I saw how easy it was to calculate and plot these points!

...however, when I look at the two points closest to Earth, $L_1$ and $L_2$, they are *way* too close to Earth:
$$
    L_1 = 183\,324 \ \mathrm{km} \\
    L_2 = 183\,212 \ \mathrm{km}
$$
-only one third of the way to the Moon! In reality, these points are more like 1.5 million kilometers from Earth, so these two points are more than a factor of eight off.

What am I missing here? Is my approach too simple, after all?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363178/2451

Comment: before looking into the problem, scale the linear dimensions of the problem, so that you're not working with $e11$

Comment: What you want to solve is an equation for a vector, $\vec r=(x,y)$. What you are solving is an equation for the real and imaginary parts of a scalar, $r=x+\mathrm{i}y$. Can you see how the two equations are, or are not, related?