# How to understand $L_4$ and $L_5$ Lagrange points gravity balance?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, lagrangian-formalism, celestial-mechanics, centrifugal-force, stability

It's relative easy to understand gravity balance of Lagrange points $L_1$, $L_2$ and $L_3$. But I am having a hard time to understand how a body would be "kind of" balanced out on Lagrange points $L_4$ and $L_5$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36092/

Comment: Thanks, but I still don´t get it...

Comment: To reopen this question, try to articulate what parts of the explanation from the other question make sense and to be more specific about where your confusion is.

Answer (score 1):

a small body occupying L4 or L5 point around a planet completes the full circle both around the planet and the star while the planet itself completes the full circle around the star in the same time span. By the way, L4 and L5 are the only stable Lagrange points, if there is a small perturbation on a body in L4 or L5 point, it must be above some threshold for the body to leave the Lagrange point it was resting in.