# Large mass body on Lagrange point L4/5

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, stability, three-body-problem

[Lagrange points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point) L4 and L5 are stable for a test particle. But what happens if instead the body at L4/5 (let's call it C) has a mass significant enough that its gravitational pull on the other two (let's call them A and B) is not negligible anymore? It is rather well know that a ternary system with similar masses is not stable, unless it is strongly hierarchical, i.e. two of the bodies form a close binary system, and the third one orbits much farther away. All observed ternary system are such. But what would be the mass threshold of C beyond which L4/5 would not be stable anymore?

Comment: Note that even for the restricted 3-body problem, the stability of $L_4$ & $L_5$ depend on the mass-ratio of the two massive bodies, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36092/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: I think you know the Sundman stability equations for a three body system?