# How wide is the $L_4$ and $L_5$ Moon-Earth Lagrangian point?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, stability

How far would an object need to be displaced from the $L_4$ and $L_5$ Lagrangian points so that it can escape returning to those points?

Comment: Related: [Why are $L_4$ and $L_5$ lagrangian points stable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36092/2451)

Comment: Useful paper discussing how the stability of $L_4$ and $L_5$ is due solely to the Coriolis effect: https://wmap.gsfc.nasa.gov/media/ContentMedia/lagrange.pdf The stability analysis here could be extended to investigate what happens in the vicinity of the points rather than at the points.